# Show what is the length x in the following triangle

Tags: geometry

[image]

In the triangle ABC where length of hypotenuse is 1 unit and length of perpendicular is a, and the base is c, show/mark out/construct the length x where

$$1^2 - \frac{1}{(1+1/x)^2}=a^2$$

a < c < 1

Comment: hmm it would require a lot of imagination to come up with a geometric interpretation. So what the equation boils down to is
$$
c = \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}
$$
I don't immediately see a geometric interpretation for this ...

Answer (score 1):

From $$c=\frac{1}{1+1/x}$$ we have $$x=\frac{c}{1-c}$$To construct *x* consider Thales' theorem. The picture below shows the construction of $x=a/b$ :       [image]

---

EDIT The picture below shows *x*. AG y BF are parallel :[image]